# Laravel CRUD - Delete - Not route found

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, crud

Error:

> Route [events.destroy] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Event-Manager-Project\resources\views\events\admin.blade.php)

In my view, admin i have this about the delete:

```
<form action="{{ route('events.destroy', $event->id) }}" method="POST">
    <a href="/admin/edit/{{$event->id}}" class="far fa-edit"></a>         
    @csrf
    @method('DELETE')
    <button type="submit" class="far fa-trash-alt" ></button>
</form>
```

In controller this:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $event = Event::find($id);
        $event->delete();
        return redirect('/admin');
    }
```

And using a route resource:

```
Route::resource('admin', 'App\Http\Controllers\EventController');
```

Comment: `resource('admin'...` would make your route `'admin.destroy'`. [Actions Handled By Resource Controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Comment: you can check route:list and check all the available routes.

Comment: Thanksss everyone!!

Answer (score -1):

change the code to this

```
<form action="{{ route('events.destroy', $event->id) }}" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" />
<input type="submit"  value="Delete" name="Delete" id="btnExc" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash" accesskey="x"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Missing CSRF, `@method('DELETE')` already handles the delete method

Comment: And `Route [events.destroy]` will still no be defined

Comment: bromber why you giving negtive

Comment: Because this answer is not useful in any way - I stated in my comments why that is. This is basically the same form as OPs, only worse, since csrf is missing and you removed OPs link.